# How to Loop/Repeat a Linear Regression in R

Tags: r, loops, repeat, linear-regression

I have figured out how to make a table in `R` with 4 variables, which I am using for multiple linear regressions.  The dependent variable (`Lung`) for each regression is taken from one column of a csv table of 22,000 columns.  One of the independent variables (`Blood`) is taken from a corresponding column of a similar table.

Each column represents the levels of a particular gene, which is why there are so many of them.  There are also two additional variables (`Age` and `Gender` of each patient).  When I enter in the linear regression equation, I use `lm(Lung[,1] ~ Blood[,1] + Age + Gender)`, which works for one gene.

I am looking for a way to input this equation and have R calculate all of the remaining columns for `Lung` and `Blood`, and hopefully output the coefficients into a table.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You want to run 22,000 linear regressions and extract the coefficients? That's simple to do from a coding standpoint.

```
set.seed(1)

# number of columns in the Lung and Blood data.frames. 22,000 for you?
n <- 5 

# dummy data
obs <- 50 # observations
Lung <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(obs*n), ncol=n))
Blood <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(obs*n), ncol=n))
Age <- sample(20:80, obs)
Gender  <- factor(rbinom(obs, 1, .5))

# run n regressions
my_lms <- lapply(1:n, function(x) lm(Lung[,x] ~ Blood[,x] + Age + Gender))

# extract just coefficients
sapply(my_lms, coef)

# if you need more info, get full summary call. now you can get whatever, like:
summaries <- lapply(my_lms, summary)
# ...coefficents with p values:
lapply(summaries, function(x) x$coefficients[, c(1,4)])
# ...or r-squared values
sapply(summaries, function(x) c(r_sq = x$r.squared, 
                                adj_r_sq = x$adj.r.squared))
```

The models are stored in a list, where model 3 (with DV Lung[, 3] and IVs Blood[,3] + Age + Gender) is in `my_lms[[3]]` and so on. You can use apply functions on the list to perform summaries, from which you can extract the numbers you want.

Comment: This is great! Can I ask how you're coding age and gender into the equation? The way I did it before was to make a table containing age/gender, and set AgeGender <- read.csv("AgeGender.csv", header=TRUE). I then set Age <- AgeGender[,1] and Gender <- AgeGender[,2].  Gender was also coded as 1 for male and 0 for female, so should I be changing 0.5 in your Gender function to 0?

Comment: Strike that, it was actually much less complicated than I was making it!  It seems to be working, thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Feel free to 'accept' the answer! :) Remember you can get info on any function by running `?function_name` at the console (e.g. `?rbinom`)

Comment: Just accepted it, thanks for the tip.  You wouldn't happen to have any additional advice for extracting the p-values and R-squared using this function, would you?

Comment: take a look at ?summary.lm

Comment: To try to get R squared, I've tried using summary(lm(Lung[,x] ~ Blood[,x] + Age + Gender))$r.squared, but it keeps saying "incorrect number of dimensions".  Any recommendations?

Comment: @JHall1020 I know it's been ages, but have you figured a way to find p.values for coefs and r-squared?

Comment: Hi, browsing this because I have a similar problem to OP. Why is it that you need to set the seed here? What is random?

Comment: just so the dummy data section is reproducible (the `rnorm()` calls )

Answer (score 3):

The question seems to be about how to call regression functions with formulas which are modified inside a loop.

Here is how you can do it in (using diamonds dataset):

```
attach(ggplot2::diamonds)
strCols = names(ggplot2::diamonds)

formula <- list(); model <- list()
for (i in 1:1) {
  formula[[i]] = paste0(strCols[7], " ~ ", strCols[7+i])
  model[[i]] = glm(formula[[i]]) 

  #then you can plot or do anything else with the result ...
  png(filename = sprintf("diamonds_price=glm(%s).png", strCols[7+i]))
  par(mfrow = c(2, 2))      
  plot(model[[i]])
  dev.off()
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sensible or not, to make the loop at least somehow work you need:

```
y<- c(1,5,6,2,5,10) # response 
x1<- c(2,12,8,1,16,17) # predictor 
x2<- c(2,14,5,1,17,17) 
predictorlist<- list("x1","x2") 
for (i in predictorlist){ 
  model <- lm(paste("y ~", i[[1]]), data=df) 
  print(summary(model)) 
}
```

The paste function will solve the problem.

Comment: The vars (y/x1/x2) need to be stored as data frame for the example to work, I think:     df <-  data.frame(
  y  = c(1,5,6,2,5,10), 
  x1 = c(2,12,8,1,16,17), 
  x2 = c(2,14,5,1,17,17) 
)

Answer (score 2):

**A tidyverse addition - with map()**

Another way - using `map2()` from the `purrr` package:

```
library(purrr)

xs <- anscombe[,1:3] # Select variables of interest
ys <- anscombe[,5:7]

map2_df(ys, xs,
        function(i,j){
          m <- lm(i ~j + x4 , data = anscombe)
          coef(m)
        })
```

The output is a dataframe (tibble) of all coefficients:

```
  `(Intercept)`     j      x4
1          4.33 0.451 -0.0987
2          6.42 0.373 -0.253 
3          2.30 0.526  0.0518
```

If more variables are changing this can be done using the `pmap()` functions

Answer (score 0):

The following approach with work with a multivariate model, where you have multiple outcomes and predictors. I will use some sample data to illustrate the idea and how it works.

```
df <- data.frame(y1=sample(1:5, size=50, replace=TRUE),
                 y2=sample(1:5, size=50, replace=TRUE),
                 x1=sample(1:5, size=50, replace=TRUE),
                 x2=sample(1:5, size=50, replace=TRUE),
                 x3=sample(1:5, size=50, replace=TRUE),
                 x4=sample(1L:2L, size=50, replace=TRUE))
df
```

The function requires a named argument for the `dv`, but uses ellipsis to indicate that you could have any number of predictors. Inside the function, you use `deparse()` and `substitute()` on the predictors and pass them on to the `reformulate()` function along with the `dv`. I included `dv=dv` inside the function so that one can see which dv the model output is associated with.

```
# custom lm function
lm_func <- function(dv, ...){
  x = sapply(substitute(...()), deparse)
  f = reformulate(termlabels=x, response=dv)
  model = eval(lm(f, data=df))
  list(dv=dv, model_summary=summary(model))
}
```

In the next step, one selects the `dvs` from the target dataframe, and names them.

```
# select the dvs and set names
dvs <- names(df)[1:2]
dvs <- purrr::set_names(dvs)
```

Finally, run a loop over the dvs and store the results.

```
# run a for loop and save the output for each loop
lm_out = list()
for (i in 1:length(dvs)){
  lm_out[[i]] = (lm_func(dvs[i], x1, x2))
  }
lm_out
```

Note: one can do some more stuff in the `lm_func`; for example, in terms of which parts of the model summary to extract.