# How can I use apply function to plot multiple graphs from same dataframe?

Tags: r, linear-regression, apply

I am new to R and was wondering if there was a way I can simplify my code using an apply function.

In my datafram there are 15 columns - y, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j .... o

Instead of:

```
plot (y~a)
plot (y~b)
.
.
.
plot (y~o)
```

Is it possible to simplify using an apply function or some other method to enact "plot" over mutiple columns?

Comment: [Does this same same post answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952653/how-to-loop-repeat-a-linear-regression-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better solution with [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) but since this is not a reproducible example, here is an approach with `matplot()`:

```r
matplot(x = mtcars[, "carb"], 
        y = mtcars[c("drat", "wt")],
        type = "b",
        pch = 1,
        xlab = "carb",
        ylab = "drat and wt")
```

[image]

The issue with `apply()` or other base functions is that you would need to determine ahead of time what the `xlim` and `ylim` are ahead of time. Otherwise your plots will vary and not look great. That's why `ggplot2` has some great features but I would need some sample data, first.